# Burn fedora to DVD, but hash is incorrect

Tags: fedora, dvd, hashsum

I downloaded Fedora-20-x86_64-DVD.iso from mirro site, and I checked the [Sha256](https://fedoraproject.org/en/static/checksums/Fedora-20-x86_64-CHECKSUM) with HashMyFiles, they are the same.

But when I burned it to DVD, and checked the hash of DVD with [Hash Codes](http://hashcodes.com/), they are DIFFERENT! (I burned 3 DVDs, they are the same different from website)

Next I booted this DVD, test this media, and it PASSED!

#### Questions

- Is that OK? The hash of this DVD is incorrect, but it can pass the test.
- What if I install with this DVD?
- Will it make problems with my computer?

Answer (score 2):

The process of burning an image to disk adds padding which alters the checksum of the disk.  [This explains it a little](http://www.troubleshooters.com/linux/coasterless.htm) (toward to bottom of the article).  I've had the same in the past and the disk works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're not comparing the various types of the DVD "images" using the same checksums. When done correctly they should all match. Given the check matched during the check during installation I'd be inclined to believe that the image was burned correctly to the DVD.

Since it's passing the checksum during installation you shouldn't experience any issues with any installations using this as a source.